# What is the most negative number that can be represented in binary?

Tags: binary, twos-complement, 16-bit

Can someone explain how to find the answer to this question? I need to find the binary representation in 16-bit 2's complement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1000 0000 0000 0000 (binary) = -2^15

is the lowest you can get :)